# How to make notification panel popup tray transparent in GNOME 3

Tags: gnome, 17.10, gnome-shell, notification-area, transparency

I've just installed Ubuntu 17.10. I am new in using GNOME Desktop Environment. Ubuntu is shipped with a slightly modified version of GNOME 3 desktop and they made the top panel transparent. But when I click Time on the panel, a calendar with notification pops up. It has a background color which quite frankly looks odd with the transparent panel. How can I make these pop up windows transparent?

This marked area need to be transparent:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calendar & message tray's colour, transparency, font etc. in GNOME are dictated by GNOME shell theme. Now in general it's very hard and not advisable to tweak the default GNOME shell theme.

As a workaround you may try using other GNOME shell themes. For example the following themes have (semi-)transparent calendar & message tray:

- [Dark Mode](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013059/)
- [Hybrid-Night-Pack](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013018/)
- [Glassful 3.14](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013022/)
- [Saydam](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013046/)

You can find many more at [GNOME-LOOK.ORG](https://www.opendesktop.org/s/Gnome).

---

#### How to install a shell theme

1. Install (GNOME) Tweaks if already not installed by running

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
2. Install and/or active the [*User Themes* extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/).
3. Get a theme of your choice from GNOME-LOOK.ORG or some other source (e.g. GitHub). It should be an archive (e.g. zip).
4. Extract the archive to `~/.themes`.
5. Launch *Tweaks* and navigate to *Appearance > Themes > Shell*.
6. Click on the drop-down box, your theme should be listed in the drop-down menu. Select it.